# How to implement rolling rank in Polars version 0.19

Tags: python-polars

From now on, polars has no inner function for rolling_rank.
Please tell me how to implement rolling rank in Polars.Thanks!

Here are some discussion about this topic:

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4808
https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9131

I don't know how to implement it. It seems that we can use pl.rolling_apply(rank_A). rank_A is defined by self.